# file_get_contents prints text not sound

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a sound file to be printed on a php page. I'm using the code below. I thought when I run this script it would have shown a sound file to download but it prints some text. What do you think I should do to fix this?

```
<?php
$mylanguage=$_GET["mylanguage"];
$soundtext=$_GET["soundtext"];

echo stream_get_contents("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/http.svc/Speak?appId=9CF5D9435A249BB484EC6DB50FFFB94C6733DEFB&language=$mylanguage&format=audio/wav&text=$soundtext");
?>
```

Comment: `stream_get_contents` does not work that way. see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the correct headers. By default, PHP sends `Content-Type: text/html`. If you send something else, you have to send the headers by yourself.

What kind of sound file is this?

Comment: it's a wav file. How should I add the audio header?

Comment: header("Content-Type: audio/vnd.wave")

Answer (score 1):

From PHP.net:

stream_get_contents

(PHP 5)

stream_get_contents — Reads remainder of a stream into a string

So it just returns a string representation of the file content. Not the file itself.

Comment: So what can I do to receive the file itself?

Answer (score 1):

`stream_get_contents` does not work that way. It requires existing opened handled.
What you need is this,

```
$url = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/http.svc/Speak?appId=9CF5D9435A249BB484EC6DB50FFFB94C6733DEFB&language=$mylanguage&format=audio/wav&text=$soundtext";
$fh = fopen($url, "rb"); // this rb makes it binary safe
$audio_data = stream_get_contents($fh)
```

To echo it to client you need appropriate `Content-Type` header. Check `/etc/mime.types` to grab your proper content type.

Suppose its a wave audio. use the following code.

```
header("Content-type: audio/x-wav");
echo $audio_data;
```

Comment: Instead of stream_get_contents, it may be better to call stream_copy_to_stream($fh, fopen('php://output','w'));

Comment: @Evert what about header? will browser recognize it?

Comment: Yea can still do header() first

Comment: @Evert Yeah I agree. In fact In my first snippet I showed how to use `stream_get_contents()` properly. Then I showed how to dump the data to browser utilizing header.

Comment: You misunderstood. Your method stores the entire request into memory ($audio_data). Using stream_copy_to_stream you can avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example on the ms api site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512420.aspx#phpexample

Within the last try block you can see the header set `header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');`

```
<?php

class AccessTokenAuthentication {
    /*
     * Get the access token.
     *
     * @param string $grantType    Grant type.
     * @param string $scopeUrl     Application Scope URL.
     * @param string $clientID     Application client ID.
     * @param string $clientSecret Application client ID.
     * @param string $authUrl      Oauth Url.
     *
     * @return string.
     */
    function getTokens($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientID, $clientSecret, $authUrl){
        try {
            //Initialize the Curl Session.
            $ch = curl_init();
            //Create the request Array.
            $paramArr = array (
                 'grant_type'    => $grantType,
                 'scope'         => $scopeUrl,
                 'client_id'     => $clientID,
                 'client_secret' => $clientSecret
            );
            //Create an Http Query.//
            $paramArr = http_build_query($paramArr);
            //Set the Curl URL.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authUrl);
            //Set HTTP POST Request.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            //Set data to POST in HTTP "POST" Operation.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramArr);
            //CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER- TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec().
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            //CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER- Set FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            //Execute the  cURL session.
            $strResponse = curl_exec($ch);
            //Get the Error Code returned by Curl.
            $curlErrno = curl_errno($ch);
            if($curlErrno){
                $curlError = curl_error($ch);
                throw new Exception($curlError);
            }
            //Close the Curl Session.
            curl_close($ch);
            //Decode the returned JSON string.
            $objResponse = json_decode($strResponse);
            if ($objResponse->error){
                throw new Exception($objResponse->error_description);
            }
            return $objResponse->access_token;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception-".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

Class HTTPTranslator {
    /*
     * Create and execute the HTTP CURL request.
     *
     * @param string $url        HTTP Url.
     * @param string $authHeader Authorization Header string.
     *
     * @return string.
     *
     */
    function curlRequest($url, $authHeader){
        //Initialize the Curl Session.
        $ch = curl_init();
        //Set the Curl url.
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        //Set the HTTP HEADER Fields.
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader));
        //CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER- TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec().
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        //CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER- Set FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
        //Execute the  cURL session.
        $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        //Get the Error Code returned by Curl.
        $curlErrno = curl_errno($ch);
        if ($curlErrno) {
            $curlError = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception($curlError);
        }
        //Close a cURL session.
        curl_close($ch);
        return $curlResponse;
    }
}
try {
    //Client ID of the application.
    $clientID       = "clientid";
    //Client Secret key of the application.
    $clientSecret = "clientsecret";
    //OAuth Url.
    $authUrl      = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/";
    //Application Scope Url
    $scopeUrl     = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com";
    //Application grant type
    $grantType    = "client_credentials";

    //Create the AccessTokenAuthentication object.
    $authObj      = new AccessTokenAuthentication();
    //Get the Access token.
    $accessToken  = $authObj->getTokens($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientID, $clientSecret, $authUrl);
    //Create the authorization Header string.
    $authHeader = "Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken;

    //Set the params.
    $inputStr = "Welcome";
    $language = 'en';
    $params = "text=$inputStr&language=$language&format=audio/mp3";

    //HTTP Speak method URL.
    $url = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Speak?$params";
    //Set the Header Content Type.
    header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');

    //Create the Translator Object.
    $translatorObj = new HTTPTranslator();

    //Call the curlRequest.
    $strResponse = $translatorObj->curlRequest($url, $authHeader);
    echo $strResponse;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```